# Center align an image regardless of width or height of image or screen

Tags: html, css

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/4EpRv/

and another here: http://jsfiddle.net/4EpRv/1/

Both show two images (one taller than wide, and the other wider than tall). The code **SHOULD** be making the images align in the middle (horizontal and vertically) and fill the space of the screen until the image hits its maximum width or height and should have 72px of padding around them (at a minimum, depending on the image size and aspect ratio)

The first example works fine on all screen sizes, but the second example breaks on portrait screens as the image appears off-canvas at the bottom.

See screenshots for the second example: http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/ipad1.png (not working on portrait) and http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/ipad2.png (working on landscape).

And see screenshots for the first example (**that work**): http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/ipad2.png and http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/ipad3.png

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-background">
        <img src="http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/halo.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.gallery {
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.gallery-background {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 72px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
}

.gallery-background:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  
    height: 100%;
}

.gallery-background img {
 max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Any ideas why the second example breaks on portrait screens if the image is wider than taller?

And how I could fix this?

**Update: Media Queries might be an option if I can apply a different rule if the screen is portrait and need to do something slightly different.**

**Update 2: The :before declaration is important, as it's what centers the image vertically, see here for an example without it: http://jsfiddle.net/4EpRv/2/ so removing that isn't an option, unless I can find an alternative. And here is proof that removing it causes the image to NOT be centered in the middle vertically: http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/NotWorking.png**

---

**Update 3: Using JavaScript has been the best solution so far, as by NOT using padding and instead positioning the element centrally I can handle all the issues: http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/2/landscape.php but can this be done in pure CSS?**

Comment: Have you [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/t8z4J/) [removing](http://jsfiddle.net/54Xg7/) the `.gallery-background:before` rule?

Comment: @kei That's what centers it!

Comment: Your second example doesn't have the image centered VERTICALLY which is what that code you are removing does! See my screenshot http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/NotWorking.png

Answer (score 1):

I retyped the post with a solution to your problem. Hope it helps.

**CSS**

```
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
       margin:0;
}
.gallery{
    position:relative; 
}

.gallery-background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:#333;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}

.gallery-background img {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $('.gallery-background').css('height',$('body').innerHeight())
    $('.gallery-background').css('width',$('body').innerWidth())
    window.onresize = function(event) {
      $('.gallery-background').css('height',$('body').innerHeight())
      $('.gallery-background').css('width',$('body').innerWidth())
    } 
})
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">

    <div class="gallery-background">
        <img src="http://dev.driz.co.uk/gallery/halo.jpg" />

    </div>
</div>
```

I have added the solution on here. I believe it is almost impossible to do without some fixed height. I have added JavaScript in to assist you.

Edit: I have fixed the question you asked with the use of JavaScript also adjusts on window resize. http://jsfiddle.net/4EpRv/9/

Edit: Fixed Scrollbar http://jsfiddle.net/4EpRv/11/

Comment: This doesn't work. Still has the image off-canvas on portrait screens for the wider image example.

Comment: Im looking in to it now. :) Sorry Im rather new to stack overflow. I miss judged the question but want to help you.

Comment: @Dave Look forward to your ideas :) Thanks

Comment: I have managed to get it in the centre height and width but the height needs to be defined. I was thinking maybe some javascript? This sorta thing can be a pain.

Comment: This isnt what you wanted but can you see where I am coming from?

http://jsfiddle.net/4EpRv/6/

Comment: It's still working in 2022, but I just tweaked the artwork http://jsfiddle.net/vr_driver/1vno9yp6/1/

Answer (score -1):

Here is a **[PEN](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/GKcem)** I created for a similar answer. There are 3 ways to vertically align your content. I think table-cell method or translate() method will suite you best.